# How to combine certain column values together in Python and make values in the other column be the means of the values combined?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Panda dataframe where one of the columns is  a sequence of numbers('sequence')many of them repeating and the other column values('binary variable') are either 1 or 0.

I have grouped by the values in the sequences column which are the same and made the column values in the binary variable be the % of entries which are non-zero in that group.

I now want to combine entries in the 'sequence' column  with the same values together and make the column values in 'binary variable' the mean of the column values of those columns that that were combined.

So my data frame looks like this:

df = pd.DataFrame([{'sequence' : [1, 1, 4,4,4 ,6], 'binary variable' : [1,0,0,1,0,1]}).

I have then used this code to group together the same values in sequence. Using this code:
df.groupby(["sequence"]).apply(lambda 'binary variable': (binary variable!= 0).sum() / binary variable.count()*100 )

I am left with the sequence columns with non-repeating values and the binary variable column now being the percentage of non zeros
.

But now I want to group some of the column values together(so for this toy example the 1 and 4 values), and have the binary variable column have values which are the mean of the percentages of say the values for 1 and 4.

This isn't terribly well worded as finding it awkward to describe it but any help would be much appreciated, I've tried to look online and had many failed attempts with code of my own but it just is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to group the table twice and take the mean each time. For the second grouping, you need to create a new column to indicate the group.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# sequence groups for final average
grps = {(1,4):[1,4],
        (5,6):[5,6]}

# initial data
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence' : [1,1,4,4,4,5,5,6], 'binvar' : [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]})

gb = df.groupby(["sequence"])['binvar'].mean().reset_index()  #.apply(lambda 'binary variable': (binary variable!= 0).sum() / binary variable.count()*100 )

def getgrp(x):  # search groups
   for k in grps:
      if x in grps[k]:
         return k

print(df.to_string(index=False))
gb['group'] = gb.apply(lambda r: getgrp(r[0]), axis = 1)

gb = gb.reset_index()
print(gb.to_string(index=False))

gb = gb[['group','binvar']].groupby("group")['binvar'].mean().reset_index()

print(gb.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
 sequence  binvar
        1       1
        1       0
        4       0
        4       1
        4       0
        5       1
        5       0
        6       1

 index  sequence    binvar   group
     0         1  0.500000  (1, 4)
     1         4  0.333333  (1, 4)
     2         5  0.500000  (5, 6)
     3         6  1.000000  (5, 6)

  group    binvar
 (1, 4)  0.416667
 (5, 6)  0.750000
```